# Trying to get property of non-object on Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Thank you for all the help in the past.
On my app, when i try to view a certain blade, it returns the error

> "Trying to get property of non-object".

It has pointed me to the blade and the section of code where the error comes from:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

@component('dashboard.frame')
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <a href="/activation-pins/create" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right">Create</a>
            Activation Pins - {{ $item->name }}
        </div>

        {{--<div class="panel-body">--}}
            {{--@if($pin_item && !$pin_item->pivot->is_paid )--}}
                {{--<form action="/activation-pins/{{ $pin_item->id }}" method="post">--}}
                    {{--<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">--}}
                    {{--<input type="hidden" name="vendor_id" value="{{ $item->vendor->id  }}">--}}
                    {{--{!! csrf_field() !!}--}}
                    {{--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Mark As Paid</button>--}}
                {{--</form>--}}
            {{--@endif--}}
        {{--</div>--}}

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>S/N</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Is Active</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                </tr>    
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @forelse($item->activation_pins as $itm)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $loop->index + 1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $itm->pin }}</td>
                         <td>
                            <span class="label label-{{ $itm->is_active ? (  $itm->is_valid ? 'info' : 'danger' ) : 'warning' }}">
                            {{ $itm->is_active ? (  $itm->is_valid ? 'active' : 'expired' ) : 'inactive' }}
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $itm->user_id ? $itm->user->email : '-' }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @empty
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6">
                            <p class="text-center">No Activation Pins</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                @endforelse       

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
@endcomponent
@endsection
```

With emphasis on:

```
<td>
    {{ $itm->user_id ? $itm->user->email : '-' }}
</td>
```

Could I be missing something? Thanks.

This is what it displays now:
   [image]

Comment: Is `$itm->user` set and is it an object? `dd($itm->user)`

Comment: OT, why don't you use Blade syntax in your blade file? That looks like a compiled Blade file from `storage/framework/views`

Comment: Yes, it is the compiled blade file, as you have indicated

Comment: I have now edited the initial question to show entire blade

Comment: do u have `user` relationship on your `$itm` model?

Comment: The more important part of my comment was the `dd($itm->user)` part, does that do anything when you put it in your `@foreach`?

Comment: @kerbholz thanks it works with `dd($itm->user)` I am so grateful.

Comment: What? That's nice to hear but I doubt that "_it works_" when you put `dd()` somewhere in your blade file. `dd()` debug `dies`, which means your script/blade ends at the `dd()`.

Comment: Well, it displays the blade when I run it. That means it works fine, don't it? Lol. I doubted at first too. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Hi @kerbholz apparently, you were right it doesn't work. What works is that when I create a new batch of pins. it works that once. But soon as I log out of my admin account and log back in, I cannot use "View Pins" blade again. instead it displays the following, as a result of the dd() we put in earlier. See code above as an edit to my question